# JQuery slider is not working on my webpage

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I don't have a clue why this doesn't work tbh. I've tried the window.onload and the .ready as well, but neither worked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title> Test </title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#slider").slider();
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I copied your code and it worked. Have you tried clearing your Cache?

Comment: change http to https. Do not use http for cdn at all, Look in the console for errors